# Why would FireFox Mobile have issues with navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

```
if (Chat.Settings.videodevice != "NONE") addMediaOption(window.videoSelect, "NONE", "NONE");
            if (Chat.Settings.audiodevice != "NONE") addMediaOption(window.audioSelect, "NONE", "NONE");
            
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true }).then((stream) => {
                navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then((devices) => {
                    let audiocount = 0;
                    let videocount = 0;
                    devices.forEach(device => {
                        let element = null;
                        let label = "";
                        if ('audioinput' === device.kind) {
                            audiocount++;
                            element = window.audioSelect;
                            label = device.label || `Microphone #${audiocount}`;
                        }
                        if ('videoinput' === device.kind) {
                            videocount++;
                            element = window.videoSelect;
                            label = device.label || `Video #${videocount}`;
                        }
                        if (!element || device.deviceId == "") return;
                        addMediaOption(element, device.deviceId, label);
                    });
                    stream.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop());
                    if (Chat.Settings.videodevice != "NONE") PreviewBroadcast(Chat.Settings.videodevice);
                });
                //document.getElementById('modal-exit').classList.add("visible");
                document.getElementById('modal-back').classList.add("visible");
                Modal.Center();
            }).catch(err => {
                Message.receive.public(`${err}`);
                console.log(err); /* handle the error */
                if (err.name == "NotFoundError" || err.name == "DevicesNotFoundError") {
                    //required track is missing
                } else if (err.name == "NotReadableError" || err.name == "TrackStartError") {
                    //webcam or mic are already in use
                } else if (err.name == "OverconstrainedError" || err.name == "ConstraintNotSatisfiedError") {
                    //constraints can not be satisfied by avb. devices
                } else if (err.name == "NotAllowedError" || err.name == "PermissionDeniedError") {
                    //permission denied in browser
                } else if (err.name == "TypeError" || err.name == "TypeError") {
                    //empty constraints object
                } else {
                    //other errors
                }
            });
```

I perform permission check with initial getUserMedia, this allows me to obtain device labels to properly identify DeviceId by name/etc.

I enumerate to populate audio/video selection so it can be saved for future use.

When a video item is selected, I run previewBroadcast which runs Navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(SavedConstraints) but problem is it doesn't catch any errors or  reveal a useable stream. This issue doesn't occur on desktop browsers at all but testing mobile FireFox failed amongst the few supported browsers.

I'm experimenting and trialing stuff by removing/adding code type stuff but curious what's causing this issue. I can say DeviceId matches 100% each time,

The problem makes getting the stream very iffy, as in it may or just doesn't work. Any tips I'd appreciate.

Comment: I've got lots to test when my phone charges back up but any suggestions I'll take it. My PreviewBroadcast function is a normal call to getUserMedia stream is sent to an element straight forward. There's never a getUserMedia call twice before it has ever processed.